# ReactJS: How to render columns horizontally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I am facing an issue to order the columns of a fetched API data horizontally. I am trying to print the data fetched from an API into a table. Anyhow the rows are well printed horizontally, but the function that I used for rows this.state.data.map() doesn't function in the same way for the columns. I think it's ES6 standard, but I am not sure. [Here is my printed issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiN1Y.jpg)

Here is my code sample:

```
class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rows: [],
            columns: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {

        fetch( "http://ickata.net/sag/api/staff/bonuses/" )
            .then( function ( response )
            {
                return response.json();
            } )
            .then( data =>
            {
             this.setState( { rows: data.rows, columns: data.columns } );
            } );

    }


    render()
    {

        return (
            <div id="container" className="container">
                <h1>Final Table with React JS</h1>
                   <table className="table">
                    <thead> {
                        this.state.columns.map(( column ) => (
                            <tr>

                                <th>{column[0]}</th>
                                <th>{column[1]}</th>
                                <th>{column[2]}</th>
                                <th>{column[3]}</th>
                            </tr>
                        ) )}
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> {
                                this.state.rows.map(( row ) => (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{row[0]}</td>
                                        <td>{row[1]}</td>
                                        <td>{row[2]}</td>
                                        <td>{row[3]}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ) )
                            }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render( <div id="container"><App /></div>, document.querySelector( 'body' ) );
```

I was able to print harcoded, if I give value to the 'th' elements, but I want to print it dynamically, in case the data within the API has been changed.

You are welcome to contribute directly to my Repo: [Fetching API data into a table](https://github.com/andimit/fetching-react-api/)

[Here is how looks like my example, when columns values has been hardcoded within 'th' elements.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuW9Q.jpg)

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you also post how it looks when you hardcode the column names?

Comment: Hi @NanduKalidindi yes, of course I updaded the question description. See this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuW9Q.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
columns: [
"Full name",
"Job title",
"Age",
"Bonus",
],
rows: [
[
"John Smith",
"team lead front-end",
30,
444.08,
],
[
"Tom Jones",
"front-end developer",
25,
333.3,
],
[
"Deborah Barnes",
"front-end developer",
21,
233.66,
],
[
"Isaac Roberson",
"technical support",
44,
353,
],
[
"Josh Brown",
"team lead back-end",
35,
353,
],
[
"Chester Mckinney",
"back-end developer",
33,
223.27,
],
[
"Ora Burton",
"back-end developer",
32,
192.92,
],
[
"Jim Brown",
"technical support",
19,
98.99,
],
],
}

class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rows: [],
            columns: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {

     
             this.setState( { rows: data.rows, columns: data.columns } );

    }


    render()
    {

        return (
            <div id="container" className="container">
                <h1>Final Table with React JS</h1>
                   <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                             {this.state.columns.map(( column, index ) =>                                  {
       
                                 return (<th>{column}</th>)
                              }
                               )
                              }
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> {
                                this.state.rows.map(( row ) => (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{row[0]}</td>
                                        <td>{row[1]}</td>
                                        <td>{row[2]}</td>
                                        <td>{row[3]}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ) )
                            }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render( <div id="container"><App /></div>, document.querySelector( 'body' ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it may help

Comment: Which framework are you using ??. You can write css for it any style sheets that is available in index.html

Comment: Simply perfect, it works as per my requirements. Thank's a lot!

Comment: I am using https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js and https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js, but it doesnt function when I add custom css file as a <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"> It doesn't read it at all.

Comment: So , which bundlers you are using ,  if you are using webpack please add css loader and style loader in configuration  and then import css file like.
import "./styles.css"

Comment: One more thing check if you are giving proper href . i can it is absolute in nature. inspect for the file in the browser and check what href it has

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you wanted to do columns[0], [1], [2] and [3]. Each column inside the map is a string. If you do columns[0] it will return you the first character from that which is what is happening in your case. `Full` Name, `Job` title, `Age` `Bonu`s are rendered in your first image. First four characters in your columns.

The `key` attribute I added is just React's requirement to provide unique keys and has nothing to do with the problem.

```
this.state.columns.map((column, index) => (
    <tr>
        <th key={"columns-" + index.toString()}>
            {column}
        </th>
    </tr>
))
```

Comment: This one, actually return all the columns values above the first row. But the above example is perfect. @NanduKalidindi I have one more question, it's looks like you will be familiar. How to customize the end view of the table? It doesnt't function with separete css file, after a short research in the web it's looks like I have to use npm package for css. But i am still in doubt?

Comment: @antdimit If you want to use `css` create a file import it into your component. Then where ever you want to apply the class just add an attribute to the element `className="some-class"`. Check out react hello world example where they `import ./App.css`. Check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vy5dnh?file=index.js